# XML to JAXB binding having nested elements?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have below XML.

```
               <elementAttributes>
                        <elementAttribute>
                            <attributeName>BIFM Service</attributeName>
                            <attributeValues>
                                <attributeValue>AssetCollector</attributeValue>
                            </attributeValues>
                        </elementAttribute>
                        <elementAttribute>
                            <attributeName>Search Service</attributeName>
                            <attributeValues>
                                <attributeValue>BudgetEstimator</attributeValue>
                            </attributeValues>
                        </elementAttribute>
                        <elementAttribute>
                            <attributeName>AgendizeExternal Service</attributeName>
                            <attributeValues>
                                <attributeValue>agendizeExternal</attributeValue>
                            </attributeValues>
                        </elementAttribute>
                    </elementAttributes>
```

Now what should be the properties/fields that JAXB class should have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
public class Test { 

    static class Element {
        @XmlElement
        String attributeName;
        @XmlElement
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="attributeValues")
        List<String> attributeValue;
    }

    @XmlElement
    List<Element> elementAttribute;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("1.xml"), Test.class);
    }
}
```